# HTML lists in Outlook +2007

Tags: html, css, outlook

I'm looking for a way to get bulleted lists in Outlook +2007

```
<ul style="margin:0; list-style-type: disc;">
    <li> Element 1 </li>
    <li> Element 2 </li>
    <li> Element 3 </li>
</ul>
```

But this just doesn't work; there are no bullets at all in Outlook while there are in Gmail.

This site says that list-style-type is supported by Outlook +2007 (https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/). However I just don't see that happening. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Try this: http://theitbros.com/bullets-in-html-email-disappearing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML emails are really annoying, aren't they? I find the most reliable way of dealing with bullet lists is to inline the bullet. That works across all email clients, with little margin variation.

Try:

```
<ul style="margin:0; list-style-type: none;">
    <li>&bull; Element 1</li>
    <li>&bull; Element 2</li>
    <li>&bull; Element 3</li>
</ul>
```